# XPath: Is there any way to select a child element of sibling which are dynamically added

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I need to touch the child element:'input' of sibling:"ng-form" , that is created dynamically when previous sibling's child : "input" is touched

I want to select and touch the input element of sibling according to my required String array data. because siblings are added as previous siblings child: input is touched

Currently this is my html form

```
<ng-form name="streamValueForm>
    <input name="name" class="ng-touched ng-valid"/>
</ng-form>

<ng-form name="streamValueForm>
    <input name="name" class="ng-untouched ng-invalid"/>
</ng-form>
```

This is I am trying to do

```
string[] values = { "dummy1", "dummy2", "dummy3" };

for( int i=0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    IWebElement set_values = m_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ng-form[@name='streamValueForm']/following-sibling::*//input[contains(@class,'ng-untouched')]"));
    set_values.Click();
    set_values.SendKeys(values[i]);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

the siblings keeps on getting added of ng-form when i touch the input element i.e child of ng-form

Comment: The `INPUT`s have no children. They also have no siblings. What are you trying to do? Show us the HTML at step 1, then how it changes after you click, and so on. You should probably take a few minutes to read up on what a sibling, child, etc. is so you can better describe the problem.

Comment: input is the child of <ng-form> whose sibling is also <ng-form> and it also has <input > as child and so on. I get it, there is slight confusion in sentence. Let me correct that.

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: @Tayyab: What you posted is not HTML. Please post the HTML **the browser** has rendered. You've posted template code, which is then interpreted by JavaScript, which generates HTML from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select input field of `ng-untouched ng-invalid` :

You can use this css selector :

```
ng-form[value='streamValueForm'] input[class*='ng-invalid']
```

Xpath would be :

```
//ng-form[@value='streamValueForm']/input[contains(@class,'ng-invalid')]
```

Comment: I have tried this in my case. But it only selects the first sibling <ng-form> child <input> everytime. I can't get it why? it should select the other sibling's child which is dynamically added.

Comment: It should select `<ng-form name="streamValueForm>
    <input name="name" class="ng-untouched ng-invalid"/>
</ng-form>` , that input.